# Suppose $A[x]$ is integrally closed then $A$ need not be UFD.

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Let $A$ be a integral domain. Suppose $A[x]$ is integrally closed then $A$ need not be integrally closed?
(In particular $A$ is not UFD.)

I was trying to find a counter example. But after long time I couldn't find any. Please give me a hint.

(I was thinking of proving  $A[x]= \mathbb Z (\sqrt{-5})[x] $  is not integrally closed. But I could not do it.  I'm not sure if it's true either.
I end up with the following statement - if $A$ is integrally closed over $B$ then for ideal $I$ of B, $A/{A\cap I}$ is integrally closed over $B/I$ which I couldn't prove or disprove either -- sorry for not showing any work. I haven't made much progress to show)

Comment: Just to try to clarify things, since the second sentence isn't a question, it is an assertion decorated with a question mark, you are asking to disprove this proposition: "If $A[x]$ is an integrally closed domain, then $A$ is an integrally closed domain." right?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes I want to prove or disprove the first statement. What i wrote in brackets after the "?" will follow as a consequence.

Comment: If A[x] is integrally closed, then A is integrally closed. Isn't this obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by [user26857](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/121097/user26857), if $A[x]$ is an integrally closed domain, then $A$ must also be an integrally closed domain. Suppose $b\in\operatorname{Frac} A$ is integral over $A$. Then $b\in \operatorname{Frac} A[x]$ is integral over $A[x]$, so it's in $A[x]$. But $A[x]\cap \operatorname{Frac} A=A$ inside $\operatorname{Frac} A[x]$, so $b\in A$.

Comment: Oh, my original problem is to find a counter example for showing it need not be UFD. I though if I show it's not integrally closed then it is not UFD. But I didn't notice this when I posted the question.  Thanks !

Comment: @LordShadow You're welcome. In the future, you should make sure your post contains your original question in addition to your attempted solution. That way you could get an answer and an appraisal of your attempts - if your attempts were misguided (this happens to everyone sometimes!) you could get learn this and also get the answer to your original question.

Comment: Thanks , next time i will do it.